# Long running mySQL query

Tags: mysql, select

First timer here.  I have a MySQL query that runs in 6 seconds as long as it's two tables.

```
sitedata is 4000 records, 10 fields.  
clientdata is 2000 records, 8 fields.
```

The query below runs in 6 seconds By adding this third table, I get 400 seconds.

That table is consolidatortable, 400 records, 12 fields.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SELECT sitedata.geozone AS geo, sitedata.week AS schweek, sitedata.PMcycle AS cycle,
       sitedata.sitenotes1 AS sitenotes1, sitedata.sitenotes2 AS sitenotes2, sitedata.sitezip AS sitezip,
       sitedata.sitecity AS sitecity, sitedata.sitestate AS sitestate,
       sitedata.siteaddress AS siteaddress, sitedata.clientsite1 AS ClientSite,
       clientdata.prefix AS prefix,
       consolidatortable.calldate AS indate, consolidatortable.duedate AS promisedate,
       consolidatortable.nte AS callnte,
       consolidatortable.description AS calldescription,
       consolidatortable.tracking AS POnumber
FROM ((sitedata INNER JOIN
       clientdata
       ON sitedata.clientname = clientdata.clientname  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
      ) INNER JOIN
      consolidatortable
      ON sitedata.portalname1 = consolidatortable.site  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);
```

Comment: Try OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to write the query more simply:

```
SELECT sd.geozone AS geo, sd.week AS schweek, sd.PMcycle AS cycle,
       sd.sitenotes1 AS sitenotes1, sd.sitenotes2 AS sitenotes2, sd.sitezip AS sitezip,
       sd.sitecity AS sitecity, sd.sitestate AS sitestate,
       sd.siteaddress AS siteaddress, sd.clientsite1 AS ClientSite,
       cd.prefix AS prefix,
       ct.calldate AS indate, ct.duedate AS promisedate,
       ct.nte AS callnte,
       ct.description AS calldescription,
       ct.tracking AS POnumber
FROM sitedata sd INNER JOIN
     clientdata cd
     ON sd.clientname = cd.clientname COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci INNER JOIN
     consolidatortable ct
     ON sd.portalname1 = ct.site COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The `FROM` clause suggests that you should have indexes on `clientdata(clientname)` and `consolidatortable(site)`.

However, the `COLLATE` probably precludes the use of any indexes.  This is probably the root cause of your performance problem.  I would suggest that you fix the tables so they all use the same collation.  Then remove the `COLLATE` from the query.